# Align-content center not working, but align-self center working

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

Recently I've been learning more about flexbox, and I just stumbled across some unexpected behavior.

I have a div, with a header element inside of it:

```html
<div>
    <h2> Hello </h2>
</div>
```

The div has

```
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

I'm trying to center my header horizontally (in the cross-axis), and my understanding is that `align-content: center`  would do that.

However, it only works if I apply `align-self: center` to the header.

Any idea what might be causing this behavior? I thought `align-content` on the flex item was equivalent to `align-self` on each of the children. Why is it only working if I specify `align-self`?

Comment: You may want to try `align-items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to apply the property to the header , Just include `align-items: center;` instead of `align-content:center` to the CSS  and it will work perfectly.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I mixed up `align-items` and `align-content`. Thanks!

Comment: I understand, CSS can be frustrating :D

Answer (score 0):

[Flex examples](https://tpverstak.ru/flex-cheatsheet/)

[official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)

Try

```
flex-direction: row;
```

Or

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center
```